# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: File not found error invoking send_keys() using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

I'm new to Selenium Automated Testing and I'm just trying to do a simple task by typing in "hi" in the text box on a web page.

My code looks like this:

```
input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
input.send_keys('hi')
```

But when I run the code I received this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: File not found : hi
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Avoid using _input_ and use a different name for your variable as that could be the cause. Can you share the webpage url?

Comment: This text box is most likely looking for a filename. Did you try giving full path with filename instead of 'hi'?

Comment: You succeeded in typing 'hi' into the text box. The problem is that the textbox is an `INPUT` that is expecting a filename... thus the error. Did you read the error message? `File not found : hi`

Answer (score 1):

You first need to import "By"

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
input=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]')
input.send_keys("hi")
```

You can also write it in (although not suggested method to do )

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]').send_keys("hi")
```

Comment: Why is the second code block _not suggested method_? What's wrong in it?

Comment: Readability and re-usability decreases . What if we want to use the same element to be cleared after entering text? we will again write the "driver.find_element" **instead store the webelement in a variable and then perform operations on it**

Comment: _Readability_? _re-usability_? It's an `<input>` element and `send_keys()` will be followed by `click()` or `submit()`. Of coase the element will become **stale**

Comment: No, you would refactor the code to separate out the `.find_element()` and store its return in variable and then do the later actions using the variable. There's nothing wrong with a one-liner here that gets refactored later. In your first case, you are storing a result in a variable that is not needed.

Comment: @DebanjanB Not all `.send_keys()` are followed by `.click()` or `.submit()`. There could easily be other actions after like YoDO suggested, e.g. `.clear()`, if you are testing invalid inputs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: File not found
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** instance was unable to find a **file** through the *character sequence* you have sent through `send_keys()`.

The relevant [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) would have helped us to debug your issue in a better way. Still it is clear from the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which you have used, that the expected *content* must be of `type` as **`file`**. Additionally it is possible, there is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) involved which checks the *contents* passed to the element if at all the *contents* refers to a **valid** *file*.

---

### Solution

You need to pass a valid *file* as an argument with `send_keys()` as follows:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']").send_keys("/path/to/filename.extension")
```